# Script errors that only show up in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, performance, safari

We just launched [a website for a client](http://tomgimbel.com), but we've run into some weird issues (like images only loading half-way) on Safari on iPhone.

While trying to troubleshoot the issue, I checked for errors in inspect element with my phone hooked up to the macbook, and I see these three errors come up when I tap refresh:

[image: there are three errors]

We've only discovered these on mobile Safari so far. We've tested the site on Windows, OSX, Firefox, Safari, Firefox, and Chrome iOS, and the only place where we see the issue is Safari on iOS. Everywhere else the site loads beautifully.

Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Did you try looking into the `\u0019` character? That looks like the cause.

Comment: I'll spare you the 'wordpress, boooo' comment. Find the setting to prevent minification of your JS scripts. This is failing you across all browsers. JQuery doesn't work and subsequent scripts fail.

Comment: How are you managing dependencies? seems like part of the issue is that jQuery is not loaded onto the page somehow.

Comment: Line 90 of his source code is the result of some WP minifier that blows it all up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. It looks like the whole file is the issue here as SoluableNonagon had pointed out.
@Brant, truust me, this was my sentiment about wordpress since the incident as well. I have a setting on the W3 Total Plugin that minified the scripts, which I've disabled. Even though the errors stopped showing up (for me at least), I still feel as if the site still behaves poorly—taking a long time to connect to the server on Safari Mobile and when it does connect the images are half-loaded. And, again, the site works (seemingly) fine on desktop.

Comment: How quickly I speak. Now we've got some other js errors. I'm assuming related to the same problem? Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/94gRod4.png

Comment: jQuery still undefined in console. That's probably the root of all your evil. CDN your jQuery reference instead of using the hosted file you have. Choose your version from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/#jquery

Comment: I would love for that to be the solution. Do you know where I can go about making that switch?